# DOCTYPE, iFrames, HTML5 - together

Tags: internet-explorer, html

I've got a situation where an iFrame needs to be embedded in a page.  The iFrame uses the HTML 5 DOCTYPE (and associated elements) and I have it working correctly in the various browsers (IE flavors, mozilla, etc.).  However, the main page that hosts the iFrame has a different DOCTYPE (`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`).

When I view the resulting page in IE9 and use the "Dev Tools" I see that Browser Mode is set to IE9 and Document Mode gets set to IE7 standards.  If I change the Document Mode to something besides Quirks, it looks fine.

Comment: You mean it's rendering in IE7 mode for both the host and the iframe? Argh, IE...

Comment: ` If I change [...] it looks fine.` Is the problem that it doesn't look good currently? What is the question?

Comment: Note that since IE9 embedded pages inherit document mode from main document. This behaviour cannot be changed.

Comment: Yes, IE7 mode for both host and iframe.  The host page looks just fine, but the iFrame looks wonky.  When the iFrame is viewed separately it looks fine and the browser is not "forced" in to IE7 standards mode

Comment: I figured out what's causing the issue.  This is in the <head> of the host page:  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" > (I don't have access to the host page).  So, this leads to another question...can I force the iFrame into a different "Compatibility Mode" with this: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" >....NOPE, no luck so far.

Comment: @coach_rob No, you definitely can't, though it was possible in IE8.

Comment: You can use an empty page that has <!DOCTYPE html> with an iframe in it that is directed at your host page and then all pages would be rendered as html5, but that may break your main page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make your iframe run in a different mode, sadly. One potential solution is to use XHTML-style syntax in your HTML5, which is valid HTML5 and will be recognised by the older rendering engine.