# Introduce another Doctype within a dynamic html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic, load

I'm trying to load a portion of the page using jquery .load(), the link is a unique .php page with manually scripted jquery code, but I face two problems:

1. Previously loaded jquery plugins will no longer works and I will need to reloaded them within a head tag and I need to add a head tag to do so.....
2. My .php code will generate an error since the .php file wasn't meant to be loaded separately but as a whole, like index.php, but I don't want the whole page to get refresh though...

Is it ok to load a new Doctype within a html div or is there a better practice, like so:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Default</title>
<script><!--jquery library here--></script>
<script><!--jquery slidwshow plugin--></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="header">header template here</div>
<div class="content">

    <!--dynamic html with doctype-->
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Default</title>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div>dynamic content loaded here</div>
        </body>
    </html>
    <!--end dynamic html with doctype-->

</div>
<div class="footer">footer template footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [DOCTYPE, iFrames, HTML5 - together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171083/doctype-iframes-html5-together)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the DOCTYPE can only be declared at the top of the page.  (And the very first non-white space characters)

To make life ever-so-interesting, `iframes` are handled differently by different browsers.

Some version of `IE` will allow an `iframe` to set its own `DOCTYPE`, others inherit from the parent frame.

I can't recall which versions do which, but I do recall running into this issue before.

**EDIT**

AH, found a discussion here -- seems to be IE9 where the `iframe` inherits from the parent:

[DOCTYPE, iFrames, HTML5 - together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171083/doctype-iframes-html5-together)

Comment: That means the .load() content cannot work with other jquery plugins?

Comment: @Vinc Never said you could use the `load()` method.   Just said you reliably set the doctype.

Comment: sorry I didn't state my question properly, what I meant was is there anyway to load/call any Javascript function within the .load() method? For example when user click on a html button and a dynamic slideshow will show up rather then just static html? Or I can achieve it without adding the new doctype?

Comment: The doc page doesn't state if `load()` strips out Javascript or not.  If it does, then you can use the regular ajax `get` method and then call `parseHTML` on your own, passing in the correct flag to make sure the Javascript doesn't get stripped.

Answer (score 0):

If your website is modular you would define the doctype in the module. Have the page load check the modules doctype and then use a switch statement in your header.

```
   global $somemodulename;

   if (($somemodulename == Music)    
   { 
     if(@file_exists(module/somemodulename/includes/doctype.php'))
     {                                                                                                   
       require_once(module/somemodulename/includes/doctype.php');
     }
   }
```

Parsing the module Sub Folder on load for doctype.php above can be done a lot different I am just trying to explain the concept.

```
   switch ($doctype) 
   {
     case 'HTML':
     $output =  '<!DOCTYPE html>'."\n";
     $output .= '<meta charset="UTF-8">'."\n";
     define('DOCTYPE', 'HTML');
     break; 
     case 'strict':
     $output =  '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">';
     define('DOCTYPE', 'strict');
     break;
     case 'transitional':
     $output = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">';
     define('DOCTYPE', 'transitional');
     break;
     case 'frameset':
     $output = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">';
     define('DOCTYPE', 'frameset');
     break;
     case 'math':
     $output = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1 plus MathML 2.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML2/dtd/xhtml-math11-f.dtd">';
     define('DOCTYPE', 'math');
     break;
     case 'xhtml11':
     $output =  '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">';
     define('DOCTYPE', 'xhtml11');
     break;
     case 'default':
     $output = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">';
     define('DOCTYPE', 'transitional');
     break;
   }
```

I already use this in PHP-Nuke Titanium and it works fine. My code is a little more elaborate but you get the gist of what I am saying. I use the doctype switch to test browser code. I took it from my browser workbench. This is used to make old modules written by other people compatible with PHP-Nuke Titanium.

You can have your header so that it is called separate if your website is not modular. That way each page load sets the **modulename** or **pagename** and the header invokes the switch on the fly.

You can embed PHP code into HTML and Vice Versa :)

This concept can be used to do exactly what you asked. I know this post was old but we all need to share our ideas. Cheers